# Connect with PayPal stopped working and gives error: Version+information+is+unavailable+for+key+aac_jws_keypair after no changes made

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the following React component to connect with PayPal (AAC).

```
 <AACComponent
   clientId="<client_id>"
   merchantId="<Merchant Account ID>"
   env="<sandbox/production>"
   pageType="<signup/login>"
   onLogin={onLogin} 
 />
```

I have been using this for several months and it returns the users auth token which is then used to get their paypal ID. Yesterday it started giving the following error:

`Version+information+is+unavailable+for+key+aac_jws_keypair`

The flow is as follows:

1. User selects "Continue with PayPal" on my website
2. They are redirected to officially sign in with PayPal
3. They login successfully
4. PayPal redirects to my app with the error: `{err: Version+information+is+unavailable+for+key+aac_jws_keypair}`

There is no error code, only that one line

**What is supposed to happen:**
It is supposed to redirect with the auth token, and it has been doing so for months. It stopped working a few days ago. I have not updated or changed anything.

This is all the error says and I cannot get in touch with anyone at PayPal to resolve this. My app is essentially broken right now due to this. Anyone else dealt with this error?

Additional info: I implemented AAC for React with [this PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/features/set-up-assisted-account-creation/)

Comment: has anything changed from an OAuth perspective on your account? sounds like it would be an issue regarding that which you would have taken care of during initial setup. Make sure that your secret key didn’t get invalidated somehow and is still active for your prod clientId.

Comment: Everything is the same for Oauth in my account. Would I be notified if my key was invalidated?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue too

Comment: @Nick I am starting to think PayPal broke something. I have heard several people had their production "Connect with PayPal" broke at the same time mine went down.

Comment: @GrantSingleton Agreed.  Certainly seems like something changed on their side.  It could be that they introduced a bug, or that they changed a policy that requires action on our side.  Either way, I'm 99% sure it was caused by changes on the Paypal side.  I checked and my implementation still matches their published documentation.

We opened a support ticket.  I'll update here if I find any action required on our part.

Comment: Agreed @Nick. I also submitted a ticket and will post about it here if anything comes of it.

Comment: Have you tried renew you client id, looks like something has expired

Comment: @flakerimi I already confirmed that this is not the case but thank you. It has now been two weeks and PayPal customer support is completely useless.

Comment: I don't have any information on the cause, but things are working again.

Comment: @Nick I just checked and it's working now for me also! This further confirms that PayPal indeed broke something on their end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an expired cert on one of Paypal's systems.  It should be working now.  They have updated the cert, and if you are validating against a known cert, you may need to get the new cert and import it. The following is from Paypal customer support:

> The PayPal Product Developers have pushed a fix for this issue. If you
> are still experiencing it, you may have a certificate that needs to be
> re-imported. There was a certificate that expired on April 29 2021.
>
> I will be getting the certificate details from the PayPal Product
> Developers, if you need it.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience this issue has caused. Thank you for
> using PayPal and have a wonderful day!
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Jennifer Global Technical Support PayPal, Inc.

Comment: Now that I'm reading it again, the date is after we started experiencing the problem... but they do appear to have fixed it.

Comment: Yeah I think this still may have been the issue though. They did not recognize there was even an issue for so long that I would not be surprised if this date is wrong.